# How does git know the sha1 name of the pack files?

Tags: git

Hypothetical situation:
I have a git repository, I have the index, HEAD, refs, packed-refs etc.
I don't know the names of the pack files in .git/objects/pack

How does git figure out the name of the pack files? Is there a way to calculate the name of the pack files from the index file?

Update:
.git/objects/info/packs is the closest I'm gonna get to what I'm looking for. This file is not always present though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, git just reads the contents of the `objects/pack` directory: it does not know a priori what the pack file SHA-1 values will be.  However, when it goes to make a *new* pack file, it does calculate an SHA-1 and use that for the name of the pack file; and the name of the index is necessarily the same as the name of the pack-file, so if

```
objects/pack/pack-1713881825f0238230418a7f843a8c9af9b70eea.pack
```

exists, then

```
objects/pack/pack-1713881825f0238230418a7f843a8c9af9b70eea.idx
```

should also exist, for instance (these names found by looking in a directory, there's no particular significance to these SHA-1s).

There may also be `.keep` and `.bitmap` files corresponding to any given SHA-1 (bitmaps appear to be new in git 2.0.0).

For more amusing enlightenment on pack files, see

```
Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt
```

in the git source. :-)

Comment: Finally figured something out. A list of all pack files is (sometimes?) located in .git/objects/info/packs, which was actually what I was looking for. Just wanted to give an update.

Comment: It's definitely "sometimes" (not "always") as this directory exists but is empty in several git repos I checked (and non-empty in others).  `Documentation/gitrepository-layout.txt` says this is specifically for dumb transports, but see also `git help repository-layout` which mentions `git repack` as creating it.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, but it seems like the best option I have so far unfortunately. Calculating the pack SHA without disk access seems impossible (or at least very hard) from my understanding.